# Can you prevent RavenDB from overwriting a document that has been manually inserted?

Tags: ravendb

I had a document in my Beta RavenDB instance with an id of:

```
document-65
```

I created a new RavenDB instance (Live) and copied the document from Beta to Live - opened the RavenDB Management, clicked on `New` and pasted the contents of the document into the 'Data' bit. I gave it the ID: `document-65` as in the Beta.

All was working well, until someone recently created a new Document and overwrote the existing one. I did the copy this way as I had one document to copy, so time-wise this seemed quickest and most effective.

I presume it's Raven auto generating an ID for me, and that's something I'll have to live with now, but what I want to know is:

Can I prevent this happening?

Can I tell HiLo (or whatever) to use ID's > 65 from now on in? (If I did this again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set optimistic concurrency = true to get RavenDB to check it for you.
see: http://ravendb.net/kb/16/using-optimistic-concurrency-in-real-world-scenarios